# RegionPlot shading the wrong region

Tags: plotting, regions

```
f[k_, α_, N_] := Sum[Sin[k*m/2]^2/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, N}]

ContourPlot[(f[k, 1, 1000] - 2 A^2) == 0, {k, -π, π}, {A, 0, 
  2}, FrameLabel -> {"k", "A"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I want to shade the region above each of the two curves shown below using `RegionPlot`.  To do this, I tried:

```
RegionPlot[(f[k, 1, 1000] - 2 A^2) < 0 , {k, -π, π}, {A, 0, 
  2}, FrameLabel -> {"k", "A"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

but this yields a region being shaded but does not have the "kink" part. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4` can improve the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ContourPlot` to do this.

```
ContourPlot[(f[k, 1, 1000] - 2 A^2), {k, -π, π}, {A, 0, 2}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "A"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how it works? e.g, what does "Contours ->{0}" do?

Comment: @KZ-Spectra We can read the `Contours`  in Mathematica documents. 
 https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Contours.html `Contous` can set the level sets and `ContourShading` can shading the level sets.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ListContourPlot`:

```
expr = f[k, 1, 1000] - 2 A^2;
sty = {Style["k", Black, 14], Style["A", Black, 14]};

ListContourPlot[Transpose@Table[expr, {k, -π, π, π/10}, {A, 0, 2, 0.05}],
Contours -> {0}, FrameLabel -> sty, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium], 
ColorFunction -> (If[# < 0, Darker[Blue, Abs[#]], Lighter[Cyan, #]] &), 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Darker[Blue], Thickness[0.0025]]]
```

[image]